# How to run conditional scripts based on database in the flyway?

Tags: flyway

How to run conditional scripts based on the database in the flyway. For example, some script needs to run as the main script and some to be run on a specific database. Is it possible this way in the flyway?

Answer (score 2):

My advice would be to save the target-specific scripts in a different subfolder (ie, a subfolder for each target) and when "migrating", specify flyway.locations differently depending on the target.

Comment: Then how the versioning work for sub folder? Also in which target the version information need to be saved?

Comment: All targets will have their own schema history table that is a log of which migrations have been applied. I'm not sure I understand your question about how it will work for the sub folder. The Flyway target only knows about the migrations that are offered to it via the flyway.locations property.